# Read .sql files with Azure Automation runbook

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to connect my powershell runbook to a storage account (blob) to read .sql files and execute them in my Azure SQL Database.

1. Connect to a blob container
2. Read the script on .sql file
3. Execute the script on the db

When I try Invoke-Sqlcmd, it requires a dedicated storage to store the file. However, runbooks work serverless and there is no storage I can use for the files, as far as I know.

Is there a way to only read the files (without moving them around) via powershell runbook or can I store the files to read with it?

Comment: Invoke-SQLcmd requires a query (command.text) with parameters.  The data in the files have to be loaded into a variable.  The command is really using the same functions as SQLDMD.EXe.  The SQL server has a number of utilities that you can call .  I do not believe any allows a direct upload of a file.  See following for more info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: _When I try Invoke-Sqlcmd, it requires a dedicated storage to store the file_ can you explain further? What makes you think the cmdlet requires dedicated storage?

Comment: You may create stored procedures with the content of those .SQL files and run them stored procedures from the Runbooks.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo For generic maintenance tasks this could be a good option but, in this case, there are several hundred dbs and many ad-hoc queries that I want to execute with some/all dbs. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I think this is how it works: Instead of reading the files and executing them in a serverless way, Invoke-Sqlcmd pulls the files to the server where powershell is hosted first. Only then it can read the .sql files. I am not hundred percent sure about this and couldn't find a useful article about how I can do it serverless. Thanks!

Comment: @Strayda in that case then consider using Elastic Jobs, that allow you to run jobs on all databases or servers, and on a subset of them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview?view=azuresql

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo Forgot to mention, it needs to be integrated to a private endpoint. The elastic jobs feature is still in preview for some reason. It does not support PEs.

Comment: _Invoke-Sqlcmd pulls the files to the server where powershell is hosted first_ can you perhaps post the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command that you are using, and what logs you are getting out out Azure Automation?

Comment: @Strayda Can you provide some more information so that community will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a SQL saved in a file in the Azure blob storage within Azure run book using the following approach.

```
# The accountName and accountKey are needed to get into the storage account.
# I recommend saving these as credentials in the automation account
$accountName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$accountKey = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
$containerName = "container-name"
$sqlFile = "sql-file.sql"

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey
$container_client = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $context
$source_blob_client = $container_client.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($sqlFile)

#download the blob as text into memory
$sqlFromFile = $source_blob_client.DownloadText()

# The following 'MyCredential' is saved a credential in the automation account   
$SQLServerCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'MyCredential'
#Import the SQL Server Name from the Automation variable.
$SQL_Server_Name = "myhsm-db-eu.database.windows.net"
#Import the SQL DB from the Automation variable.
$SQL_DB_Name = "db_name"


# Execute query
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$SQL_Server_Name" -Database "$SQL_DB_Name" -Credential $SQLServerCred -Query "$sqlFromFile"
```

I hope this helps. Thanks